# Android - Make AdMob ad disappear after click?

Tags: android, admob, ads

So I have a regular admob banner ad in my android apps.
The problem is, they don't disappear after the use clicks them, and they hide some of the app view.

What can I do? Is it possible to make Admob ads disappear after you click them?

Thanks in advance!

Dvir

Comment: yes hide  the layout on basis of flag

Comment: Can you please be more specific or provide an online resource/ example?
Thanks!

Comment: When you click the admob you can take a flag and make it true and on resume you can make the layout visible or gone depending on this flag

Comment: Is it okay with Google? Do they approve this or I might get a warning?

Comment: i have not read about it so far .But you won't get an exception on this , that i am sure

Comment: That could be forcing users to click the ad to see the hidden content - it's against the Google's rules